# RegEx: Get multiline LDAP entry

Tags: regex, grep, ldap

I'm trying to capture an entire LDAP entry from `dn:.+` to the entry's last line, but stopping at last line before next entry, e.g., \n#entry-id: 8266. My trial and error using `egrep` is getting absolutely nowhere. NOTE: I'm using exported ldif files where the data resides, fwiw.

Closest I've come is with `egrep "dn: cn=name,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com.+.|\n*.+\n"` but no output on terminal. I've tested the actual regex on regexr.com. I understand that is a completey different env.

Thanks in advance!

---

Sample Data:

```
dn: cn=name,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com \
shadowLastChange: 17492 \
userPassword: password \
sn: Last \
givenName: First \
cn: first \
mail: name@example.com \
displayName: First Last \
o: University \
ou: Dept. \
objectClass: top \
objectClass: person

\# entry-id: 8266
```

Comment: LDAP entries don't have lines. There is therefore no such thing as a multi-line LDAP entry. What you are actually talking about is the LDIF *representation* of an LDAP entry. But the example you provided logically consists of only one line, because of the line-terminator-escaping backslashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk '/entry-id/{found=""} /^dn:/{found=1} found' Input_file
```

***OR*** in case you want to print only 1 set from `dn:` before `entry-id:` then try following code:

```
awk '/entry-id/{exit} /^dn:/{found=1} found' Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

If the data is always structured like that, and using awk is an option, you can use a [range](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Ranges.html) starting with `dn:` and ending with `entry-id:` and only print the lines that do not have entry-id:

```
awk '/^dn:/,/entry-id/ {
  if(!/entry-id:/){print}
}' file
```

[Awk demo](https://tio.run/##ZVDRSsMwFH3PV1znwxTqgkOmBgrCxCeRvfgWhCy5W6NtEpLUWua@vaZdK4Jv557DOefeuxWh6DqUhYWZMgykyY2oMLN1vkHrSsyUzPFLVCOUtgJOQiGUbZ5FiOtCmD0yuL69uV8C56QO6DcihMZ6xcCNqFdCiu8tPd7rTzQvqYjBk/YnTiZ9Nw2V0CWDfpWHsX0xVHOidHClaP@ap1TL4NWkZB90bAeiZvCILi6GYfuOMq7LtBKDaN0/ziWjNYTwc0ATfXul0wV3y9VqBt8gmg@Y07f0I5rRSaZwIKB3F2e/DKOXB@e1iUdynHfdDw)

Answer (score 0):

`egrep` uses extended regexp (equivalent to `grep -E`). Prefer `grep -P` (perl regexp) instead.
The `-z` flag makes your regex multiline:

```
grep -Pz "dn(\n|.)*?(\n\n|$)"
```

This matches with `dn` followed by any number of characters (or new line) until (`?` makes the preceding expression lazy instead of greedy) the next occurrence of `\n\n` or end of file (`$`)